# Ctrl + Alt not working on Ubuntu but does on Windows

Tags: keyboard

I have a laptop with dual boot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 installed. On both OSs I have Canadian French keyboard running. On Ubuntu for some reason nothing with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> work. I can't type `{` `}`, `[` `]`, `@` etc.. but on Windows 10 it works fine.

I also noticed whatever keyboard language I use on Ubuntu, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> seems to not work.

I have qwerty Acer E 15 laptop if it helps.

Comment: We have different keyboard combinations. For instance, when I want to make an @, I use altgr+2. If alt+ctrl doesn't work, then alt+ctrl+t would not open a terminal window on your Ubuntu system. If it does, then alt+ctrl does work and you only need to look up some keyboard combos.

Comment: @Jo-ErlendSchinstad Thanks you! I just tryed Ctrl +alt+t and it does open the terminal. But I dont have the altgr key on my keyboard. Is there a way to change it to ctrl+alt? I am new to ubuntu

Comment: Have you tried the OnBoard keyboard?

Comment: You might want to read up on compose: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey